# Clojurescript advanced compilation unreachable-code

Tags: clojurescript

I have just added a new library(https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tempura/blob/master/README.md ) to my Clojurescript project.

```
WARNING: /matter/titan/source/titan-ui/out/taoensso/tempura/impl.js:96: WARNING - unreachable code}catch (e20422){if((e20422 instanceof Error)){
```

I also get this error :

```
Use of undeclared Var goog.structs/Map
(def ^:private coerce-xhr-params "Returns [<uri> <?data>]"
(let [url-encode
(fn url-encode
([params]
(when (seq params)
(-> params clj->js gstructs/Map. gquery-data/createFromMap .toString)))
                   ^---
([uri params]
(let [qstr (url-encode params)
          uri-with-query (if (str/blank? qstr) uri (str uri "?" qstr))]
          [uri-with-query nil])))
```

Do I need to write an 'extern' for this? What does that look like?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from your code and question details, but I assume you're having trouble with library call in advanced compilation mode.

The modern simple way is to skip externs thing altogether and just write calls/gets not in interop form, but by using `https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops` library.

You won't have to do anything else then - all your code will survive advanced compilation by default, no externs needed!

e.g. `(.-nativeProp obj)` would look like `(oget obj "nativeProp")`, and `ocall` is used for function calls correspondingly.

Comment: cljs-oops is good, the docs are not the best but can be found at https://cljdoc.org/d/binaryage/oops/0.7.2/doc/readme